# Chrome Inspector shows different width of page than is monitor

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Why does Dev Inspector in Chrome shows width of 100% width page in different width than I have on my monitor? I have 1920x1080 monitor and in full screen I don't get 1920 but only 1519 pixels. This number changes by the zoom. 
What is reason behind this? It makes hard to code style when I don't have a proper information about a width.

[image: Example]

Comment: Can you link to a page where I can reproduce?

Answer (score 0):

When you give an element a width of 100% in CSS, you’re basically saying “Make this element’s content area exactly equal to the explicit width of its parent — but only if its parent has an explicit width.” So, if you have a parent container that’s 400px wide, a child element given a width of 100% will also be 400px wide, and will still be subject to margins, paddings, and borders — on top of the 100% width setting.

Have a look here for more https://www.impressivewebs.com/width-100-percent-css/